# How to prevent spring hateoas to return empty links?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I am generating response classes that *could* provide links.
I'd like to avoid the links attribute to show in case no link is provided, as for example now I'm getting:

```
{
"links": [], <--not the best
"id": 1,
"category": {
  "links": [],
  "id": 3
}
```

I would instead like to have:

```
{
"id": 1,
"category": {
  "id": 3
},
```

I tried defining a global mapper:

```
@Configuration
 public class JacksonConfig {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper; //reuse the pre-configured mapper


@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
}
 }
```

And for every other dto I have it works...except for the hateoas links!
What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**

I think I made a step further. It only happens when the RepresentationModel is in a List:

```
@GetMapping("/pet")
public ResponseEntity<List<Pet>> getPets(){ <-- this returns empty links

@GetMapping("/pet")
public ResponseEntity<Pet> getPet(){ <-- this doesn't
```

Comment: Can you post your response classes?

Comment: Done, I  also think I have an hint but cannot understand how to fix :(